# Appending new paragraphs

Tags: javascript, append

Been stuck on this for a while now, trying to add multiple new p elements to a div but it is just adding the content to the first one instead of creating a new one.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
var output = document.getElementById('output');
```

function on button press

```
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"+"\n"));
output.appendChild(p);
```

Thanks for any help in advance, I need a solution where i'm allowed an infinite amount of new paragraphs until a condition is met.

Comment: ... Because you only create a single paragraph and append text nodes to it on the click, counter to what you say you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Dave, how would I go about creating a new paragraph each time. I'm new to javascript.

Comment: You'll want to call `document.createElement("p");` each time, for starters. Move that line into your button-press function.

Comment: The same way you do now, but more often.

Comment: Thanks Paul, moved the document.createElement("p"); and it's working fine.

Comment: I know it's unrelated but any idea how I would then clear all of the p elements based on a certain condition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create only one paragraph but append multiple text nodes in it. Despite on how it looks, `output.appendChild(p)` doesn't append initial `p` more then once. In fact, if the element is already in DOM (like in your case afther the first click), `appendChild` simply moves element to a new location. But in your case new location is the same as the original. So as the result, you only create new text node with every click.

You need to create new HTMLParagraphElement on every click:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"+"\n"));
    output.appendChild(p);
};
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```